# Solr_query not working in terminal, but query can be executed on Solr admin page

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am using Solr within my datastax enterprise package.

I have created a cassandra cluster which is using Solr and created a Solr core which is working properly.

I am able to see my core on the Solr admin page.....and I can execute queries using the admin page.

However, when I attempt to use the string "solr_query" on my terminal to make a search, I am getting this error......

Bad Request: No search handler with name: solr_query found for Solr query: q=family_size%3A6, did you miss to configure it?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your query? Are you able to run queries from the solr admin console?

Comment: My query is as follows:  SELECT id FROM nhanes_ks.nhanes WHERE solr_query='family_size:6';

Comment: Yes, I can and have run queries from the solr admin console.  Also, I saw your other post a couple of days ago... and that didn't work

Comment: The way I indexed is as follows:  $ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/nhanes_ks.nhanes/solrconfig.xml --data-binary @solrconfig.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

 

$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/nhanes_ks.nhanes/schema.xml --data-binary (at)schema.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

$ curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=nhanes_ks.nhanes"

Comment: I now have it working, had it automatically create the xml index.  However, now I am getting this strange error:                      Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run CQL Solr queries in DSE Search 4.6 you have to configure a special purpose search handler in your solrconfig.xml, as described here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCql.html

Comment: sbtourist, I attempted this in my solrconfig.xml, still getting the error message:   cqlsh:nhanes_ks> SELECT id FROM nhanes WHERE solr_query='family_size:6';
Bad Request: No search handler with name: solr_query found for Solr query: q=family_size%3A6, did you miss to configure it?

Comment: pasted this in my xml: <requestHandler class="com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.component.CqlSearchHandler" name="solr_query" />

Comment: I now have it working, had it automatically create the xml index.  However, now I am getting this strange error:                      Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966440/normal-query-on-cassandra-using-datastax-enterprise-works-but-not-solr-query will provide more info